# SetInterval and Callback with Arrow Functions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that uses setInterval.  I want to be able to use the component's `this` inside setInterval but `this` becomes the window inside setInterval, and then `this` becomes `undefined` in the callback.

Both are arrow functions so this feels unexpected to me but there's probably an innerworking that I'm not aware of at this point.

Here's the example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.hasEndedTimer = this.hasEndedTimer.bind(this)
    ...
    this.hasEndedTimer(()=>{
      // the callback 'this' is now undefined? Even though an arrow 
      function?    
    })      
  }
...
  hasEndedTimer(callback) {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      // 'this' is now the window instead of the component? Even though arrow
      if(somecondition()) callback()
    }, 1000)
  }

...
}
```

**Can I maintain the `this` context of the react component inside `setInterval`?**

NOTE: If I change the arrow function in `setInterval` to an anonymous function that I bind `this` to, the `this` context remains the component.

```
  hasEndedTimer(callback) {
    const intervalId = setInterval((function() {
      // 'this' is now the component. Works as expected.
      if(somecondition()) callback()
    }).bind(this), 1000)
  }
```

Comment: Also the `constructor` needs to take `props` as an argument and pass that to `super()`. And to bind functions to your class instance you should either declare it in the constructor with `this.myFunction =` or in class scope with the class property syntax. You may have mixed that up.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, that was just my shorthand syntax to show the example.  That's actually happening in the code. I've updated above to reflect. I don't believe props is required in the constructor if you aren't passing it to super.

Comment: It is required, and it doesn't matter if you use any props or not. You call super to properly initialize the react component base class and it expects the props as the first parameter.

Comment: Interesting cause many components in our application just call super without passing any props when we don't use props in the component.  Is there a side affect that we aren't seeing? It definitely compiles and runs as expected. The example above is decent for expressing this since the example never uses props and the constructor and super dont bring them in

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you.

### Constructor must have super().

The react Component doc't have this expression object.It has to get this from the father component.So have to use super() to get this.

### And you need to bind hasEndedTimer in the constructor.

If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

```
this.hasEndedTimer = this.hasEndedTimer.bind(this)
```

And if using arrow function,there is no need to bind(this).

### About this in setInterval,it's different.

"This" usually points to window or global.When this needs to point to class  instance, we should use bind to bind this to callback.Like this

```
declare (){
  console.log(...);
};
setInterval(this.declare.bind(this), 1000);
```

So,the function you set inside the setInterval is actually a callback function, and could make this point to class instance.So "this" works well.

### About the arrow function.

Arrow function doesn't have this itself, it has to inherit from the upper from scope chain.And there is no need to use bind.The ways you define "this.hasEndedTime" arrow function has something wrong.

```
this.hasEndedTimer = ()=>{
   ...  
}
//how to use it 
this.hasEndedTimer()
```

And setInterval in arrow function should should pay attention to "this" inside the funtion.

## "This" inside function is fixed and point to the scope defined not used.Here is an example.

```
function Timer() {
  this.s1 = 0;
  setInterval(() => this.s1++, 1000);
}
var timer = new Timer();
setTimeout(() => console.log('s1: ', timer.s1), 3100);
```

Comment: For the constructor requiring super and hasEnded being bound in the constructor, I just left that out in my haste to get an example up. I've updated my question. 

I guess I still don't follow why an arrow function doesn't work here instead of a class instance?

Comment: @user3331142 I have added something about arrow function.